# JAVA How to split by space and store into double array

Tags: java, arrays, split

how can I read data from a text file, split and store each word/number into an array?

Comment: `Arrays.stream(str.split(" ")).skip(1).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray();`

Answer (score 1):

You should read the line of from the file as a String, split that and convert to double. Try this:

```
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("path/to/file"));

        String str = scan.nextLine();

        String[] split = str.split("\\s+");

        // remove first element
        String[] x = new String[split.length-1];
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i] = split[i+1];
        }

        double[] numbers = new double[x.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = Double.parseDouble(x[i]);
        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I also added a bit to remove the first element since is not a `double`. You could condense the two for-loops together, avoiding having a separate x-array. This can be done as follows:

```
        String[] split = str.split("\\s+");

        // create double array while ignoring the first element 
        double[] numbers = new double[split.length-1];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers .length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = Double.parseDouble(split[i+1]);
        }
```

Comment: Don't really need `String[] x`. Just load the double array of the correct size

Comment: @TM00: You Don't need the `String[] x = ...` and the for loop to remove the first at all. Just ignore the first element on the next for loop where you are converting string[] to double[].

Comment: @cricket_007 that is true, I added an additional piece of code to the answer to show how that can be done.

Comment: Why does nobody use try-with-resources?